# Searching in multiple files using findstr, only proceeding with the resulting files? (cmd)

Tags: search, cmd, findstr

I'm currently working on a project where I search hundreds of files using findstr in the command line. If I find the string which I searched for, I want to proceed with this exact file (and the other ones that include my string).
So in my case:
I searched for the string `WRI2016` by using:

```
H:\KOBINI>findstr "WRI2016" *.ini > %temp%\xx.txt && %temp%\xx.txt
```

To see what the PC does, I save it in a `.txt` file as you can see.
So if my file includes `WRI2016` I want to extract some facts out of the file. In my case it is `NR, Kunde, WebHDAktiv, DigIDAktiv`.
But I just can't find a proper way to link both of these functions.
At first I simply printed all of the parameters:

```
H:\KOBINI>findstr "\<NR Kunde WRI2016 WebHDAktiv DigIDAktiv" *.ini > %temp%\xx.csv && %temp%\xx.csv
```

I also played around using the `if` command but that didn't really work out. I'm pretty new to this stuff as you'll see in my following tries to solve this problem:

```
H:\KOBINI>findstr "\<NR DigIDAktiv WebHDAktiv" set a =*.ini findstr "WRI2016" set b =*.ini if a EQU b > %temp%\xx.txt && %temp%\xx.txt
```

So all I wanted to achieve with that weird code was: if there is a `WRI2016` in the file, give me the remaining parameters. But that didn't work out at all.
I also tried it with using new lines for every command which didn't change a thing.

As I want this to be a `.csv` in the end I want to add a semicolon between my parameters, any chance how I could do that? I've seen versions using `-s";"` which didn't do anything for me.

Comment: Instead of a huge amount of text, you could have provided a sample text file and a sample CSV file, so it might be a bit easier to understand, what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm quite new and thought I'd give it a shot.
an example of my .ini files Looks like this:

```
> Kunde=Markt
> Nr=101381  
> [...]
> DigIDAktiv=Ja
> WebHDAktiv=Nein 
> Version=WRI2016_U2_P1
```

some files have a different Version though.
So I only want to know "NR, DigIDAktiv ..." if it's the 2016 Version.
As a result it should be sorted in a CSV, in different columns.

[My Folder Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnpTK.png)

So I search These files in order to find Version 2016 and then try to extract my Information and put it into a .csv